# Keras: output of concatenation has no parameters?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I encountered a weird problem with [tf.keras.Concatenate()](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/merge.py#L328) method. I was trying to perform a group convolution. Here is the code.

```
# C2: (None, 27, 27, 96) -> (None, 27, 27, 256).

# Split (None, 27, 27, 96) into x2 (None, 27, 27, 48)
pool1_1 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, :, :, :48])(pool1)
pool1_2 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, :, :, 48:])(pool1)  

#####################
# Grouped convolution.
#####################
conv2_1 =  Conv2D(filters=128,
                     kernel_size=(5,5),
                     activation='relu',
                     padding='same',
                     name='conv2_1')(pool1_1)

conv2_2 =  Conv2D(filters=128,
                     kernel_size=(5,5),
                     activation='relu',
                     padding='same',
                     name='conv2_2')(pool1_2)

conv2 = Concatenate(name='conv2', axis=-1)([conv2_1, conv2_2])
```

Here is the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nebaO.png).

As you can see, after the concatenation, the resulting layer has 0 parameter. I expected it to have 153728 * 2 parameters. Why is that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Concatenate` layers do not have parameters, well because, they do not have any learnable weights, the operation is just concatenation, no learning done in that layer at all.

So you assumption that the layer has to have parameters is just wrong.

Comment: Okay thanks! Is there any workaround ? Thing is, I really need to have parameters for the merged layer.

Comment: @FerdinandMom What do you mean a workaround?, what would the parameters do in this layer? What would be learned?

Comment: Thing is, I'm trying to load weights from a caffe model to a keras model. Weights are of shape (5, 5, 48, 256) for this layer in caffe model.  If I do concatenation, i have to specify 128 filters for the 2 convolutions. But then, I will not be able to load weight to those 2 layers since they will have 128 filters instead of 256. So my only solution was to load the weights to the merged layer. Problem: merged layer has no parameters.

Comment: @FerdinandMom First of all, you have here a clear XY problem, you are asking what you think the solution is, instead of asking about the actual problem. Second, the solution to this is not "make Concatenate have parameters", but just split the weights you have and load them into individual Conv2D layers.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I should change the title of the post to "Keras: output of concatenation has no parameters ?"

Comment: @FerdinandMom No, better ask a new question (if you need help of course).